# rowNum of jqGrid with datatype json when onPaging event raised

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

I am trying to save jqGrid settings on server, like filter, sort order and others. All work fine, except **rowNum** setting. To save this parameter i am using event onPaging.

```
onPaging : function(pgButton){
    if (pgButton == 'records'){
        var rec_per_page = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'rowNum');
        //next sending "rec_per_page" param to server
    }
}
```

Let's say user change value of rowNum from 50 to 100 records per page. When datatype is set to local it work correctly, but if datatype is set to json, variable **rec_per_page** will be contain 50 instead of 100.
How can i get the correct value of rowNum after user change it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
onPaging : function(pgButton){
    if (pgButton == 'records'){
      setTimeout(function() { alert(grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'rowNum')); }, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! As i understand from reading about setTimeout(..., 0), this will use minimum delay, determined by the browser and it is not 0 milliseconds. So it will not execute immediately. But will it work always? I mean, if it raised after onPaging ajax call of jqgrid, is time of ajax response can affect?

Comment: Well, it will work in the current (4.6.0 at the time of this writing) version of jqgrid, because it sets the internal paging properties (such as rowNum) right after calling the onPaging handler. If the implementation was changed to set these properties after populating the grid, this solution would stop working. It's a hack, not a bulletproof solution; it would be definitely better if jqgrid provided two events, one before paging and one after paging.

Answer (score 0):

I use this approach:

```
onPaging : function(pgButton) {
        if (pgButton == 'records') {
            alert($('.ui-pg-selbox').val());
        }
    }
```

Looks like more beautifull structure :)

Comment: This most likely will bring you wrong results if you have several grids on the page?